# ElasticSearch source first level attributes alone

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am indexing below json into es.

```
{
 "id":"1234",
 "ad":{
                  "id": "50419957",
                  "priority": 1
                },
"div":["adb", "dfg"],
"startDate": 1533193200000,
"endDate": 1534489199000
}
```

Is it possible to filter out the primitive properties(id,startDate,endDate) alone?

I have more than 50 fields in the json.There are many nested objects as well. I need to filter out the first level attributes(that too only the string and numbers, not the arrays).

I cannot have

> includes/excludes with _source

as there are many dynamic fields as well.

Comment: hmm what do you mean by filter? first level is the easiest to work with, u can even do a get request with param `q=id:1234`

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is when I make a query and in the _source returned, I need to omit some values. Basically I dont need the whole json indexed, but only selected fields from it. I cannot hardcode all the includes/excludes , is it possible to include/exclude fields based on type? I need only the first level attributes, not the nested attributes like ad,div etc

Comment: I can think only on naming those "primitive" type with a prefix for example "p_startDate" and use include/exclude with wildcard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `_source` param

e.g.

```
_source=id
```

will return all document's id only,

you can even do multiple fields:

```
_source=id,startDate,endDate
```

will return all the fields' id,startDate and endDate

for more info and also using query structure refer to the documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html

**EDIT 1**

there isn't a way to include/exclude based on type.

However, if you need the type you can parse the _mapping for your type, grab desired data (in your case string and long of the first level) and automate things out.

Comment: He actually said that he cannot use includes/excludes with _source, and your answer relay on _source.include